# consulta eloquent no me trae registros cuando realizo un select

Tags: php, laravel, sql, eloquent

Tengo la siguiente consulta en eloquent que me muestra los registros

```
Usuario::with(['rutas'=> function($query){
        $query ->select('rutas.*','puntosDeVenta.id_puntodeventa','puntosDeVenta.codigo')
               ->join('puntosDeVenta','puntosDeVenta.id_puntodeventa','=','rutas.id_puntodeventa')
               ->join('subcadenas','subcadenas.id_subcadena','=','puntosDeVenta.id_subcadena')
               ->where('rutas.fecha','=','2018-08-20');

        }])->get();
```

lo que retorna:

```
{
    "id_usuario": 2,
    "rut": "12345678-9",
    "nombre": "Administrador",
    "apellido": "Demo",
    "correo": "adm@portia.cl",
    "acceso": "ADMINISTRADOR",
    "id_supervisor": 1,
    "api_token": "mIJoxWmPD7YmowaS7T2GRXWlxZn5bjkrff8wijELln9shLs8d0KcBcEUkyLF",
    "imagen": "defaultAdm.png",
    "estado": "DESCONECTADO",
    "rutas": [
        {
            "id_ruta": 1,
            "id_usuario": 2,
            "id_puntodeventa": 1,
            "id_empresa": 1,
            "usuario_validador": null,
            "estado": "PENDIENTE",
            "fecha": "2018-08-20",
            "lat": "",
            "long": "",
            "hora_validacion": null,
            "hora_checkout": null,
            "hora_sincronizacion": null,
            "fecha_validacion": null,
            "TIPO": "RUTA",
            "codigo": "CE001"
        }
```

lo cual esta correcto , pero cuando cambio

```
select('rutas.*','puntosDeVenta.id_puntodeventa','puntosDeVenta.codigo')
```

por

```
select('rutas.id_ruta','puntosDeVenta.id_puntodeventa','puntosDeVenta.codigo')
```

me entrega   el campo 'ruta' vacio

```
 {
    "id_usuario": 2,
    "rut": "12345678-9",
    "nombre": "Administrador",
    "apellido": "Demo",
    "correo": "adm@portia.cl",
    "acceso": "ADMINISTRADOR",
    "id_supervisor": 1,
    "api_token": "mIJoxWmPD7YmowaS7T2GRXWlxZn5bjkrff8wijELln9shLs8d0KcBcEUkyLF",
    "imagen": "defaultAdm.png",
    "estado": "DESCONECTADO",
    "rutas": []
}
```

A que se debe como lo soluciono, probé la consulta directamente en mysql y me trae los valores

Gracias !!!